# PyTorch ImageFolder: how to sample images belonging to particular classes

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a pytorch ImageFolder. I see that the `__getitem__(index)` method of ImageFolder can get both the tensor and the class of an index. But what if I want to use ImageFolder to randomly sample a certain number of images from a class (or multiple classes) of my choosing, and then get their indices for the `__getitem__` method later? (Sort of like operating in reverse, i.e. choose class -> get index rather than choose index -> get class)

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I once tried something similar for the MNIST dataset, but sadly could not find the corresponding code for it. If I remember it correctly, I did simply iterate over custom split of the dataset, but there is by now a more native way to do so: 
Essentially, instead of having to worry about your `Dataset` class, it is more the problem of your `DataLoader`. The `Dataset` simply contains methods to reference this data; the point at which this data is actually called, though, happens in the `DataLoader`.

Unfortunately, you would have to write your own `DataLoader`, which allows you to have additional custom [samplers that only take a specific range](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#SubsetRandomSampler) . My best guess would be to have one that takes multiple Samplers (one for each class), where you pass the corresponding indices for each class, and at runtime ask for the sampler corresponding to a specific class.

AFAIK, it is not possible to have something like this with the regularly provided `DataLoader`s.
Also note that it is getting harder to keep track of when you have passed once across all your training data once (if you still want to train across all the different samples during one epoch).